# Generate complete functions set in hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

It is just a curiosity, but is there a general method (or a class of methods) that allows to derive orthonormal complete function set for a given hilbert space? (Except Gram Shmidt algorithm and manipulate other orthonormal set).

If yes there's a specific theory for this kind of problem?

Comment: All of the classical orthonormal bases came out of solving ODEs and PDEs through Fourier's separation of variables. In fact, that's the process that evolved to general notions of orthogonality and the eventual generalization of inner product space itself. Hilbert was modeling that situation in the abstract. If the space is separable, then finding a selfadjoint compact operator with no or finite dimensional null space will give you an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions. Same idea as using the ODEs and PDEs.

Comment: Are there "non classical" orthonormal bases worth to mention?

Comment: There is mention of orthonormal bases of eigenfunctions of selfadjoint integral operators or general selfadjoint compact operators, but either you can't find explicit representations, or nobody knows how to find them, or nobody cares because it's enough to know you can diagonalize. I saw this one in this forum not too long ago $Lf = \int_{0}^{1}e^{st}f(t)dt$ on $L^{2}[0,1]$. You know this operator has a complete orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions, and the OP was wondering what they were. Not easy. I don't think what you get would be considered classical.

Comment: Is there some literature on this specific subject? (as far as you know of course)

Comment: You can learn about the spectral theory of selfadjoint compact operators in a Hilbert space.That's a beautiful topic, and most every Functional Analysis book has a chapter on this topic. If you want an easy-to-read detailed book that an undergraduate can learn from on their own, I recommend Bachmann and Narici *Functional Analysis*. Or I really like the Functional Analysis book by Peter Lax for a graduate level text.

Comment: I can get this book here, do you think it could be suitable for the purpose? https://books.google.it/books?id=wkBNXonCtPIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=unbounded+linear+operator&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAGoVChMI4tT655iDxwIVARgsCh3WIQSI#v=onepage&q=unbounded%20linear%20operator&f=false

Comment: Goldberg is a clear, deep thinker. I'm not sure I would start with unbounded operators, though. I would start with bounded operators. Compact operators are bounded. What is your Math background?

Comment: I would say the closest subject i've studied is "Mathematical Physics" (when i was undergraduate). It was a course focused on complex analysis, banach and hilbert space, fourier analysis, laplace transform and distribution theory. But a general course, i'm not a mathmo, but i like this stuff. I know something about operator in general (definition for most of them), but i've found the first part of the book i mentioned pretty good and easy to understand (even if sometimes i have to review some concept).

Comment: That's all good stuff. I like Bachmann and Narici because (a) they stay at the level of Banach and Hilbert spaces and metric topology, (b) they do a great job with selfadjoint compact operators (most authors do) (c) they present the full Spectral Theorem for unbounded and bounded selffadjoint linear operators on a Hilbert space using several different approaches  and (d) the exposition is on the verbose side and is easy to read. This is a great way to build on what you've learned up to this point without getting distracted. You may well be able to read through that like a novel.